# SQL Server cursor ending transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, cursor

I have table with quantity of Articles 'ArticlesQuantity'. Articles are build from other Articles, lets name them SourceArticles.
So when user wants to build an Article, I have to do transaction with cursor in it:

```
 - for every needed SourceArticles check if its sum in 'ArticlesQuantity' > 0:
 - if there's not enough quantity of SourceArticles end transaction and remove some documents;
 - else remove SourceArticles, add Article, update some documents;
```

Question is- how can cursor 'brake' transaction. Will the Raiserror be sufficient? After rollback I have to remove document created before transaction, is it possible after Raiserror? Or would it be better to create a flag and update it in cursor like:

```
- TRANSACTION
- flag = 0
- for every needed SourceArticles check if its sum in 'ArticlesQuantity' > 0:
- if not, flag = 1
- and later, if flag == 1:
     - there's not enough quantity of SourceArticles so remove some documents, COMMIT TRAN;
     - else remove SourceArticles, add Article, update some documents, COMMIT TRAN;
```

OR maybe there is a way to do it without cursors? Something like temporary table with

```
SourceArticle_ID, SourceArticle_Needed, SourceArticle_InStorage, [SourceArticle_InStorage - SourceArticle_Needed]
```

and then check if last column values => 0

Comment: Usually I put all read-only operations and verifications before to start the transaction.

Comment: But what's going to happen when I check for needed SourceArticles, quantity will be sufficient, THEN someone else takes them, and THEN I will take them? I though I need transaction for that very reason.

Comment: but the first time you check `ArticlesQty > 0`, you  don't need a transaction. Obviously you should update it inside the transaction, and if `ActualStock < 0`rollback.